# How to write a regular expression pattern for this scenario

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the special character appearence in my below sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PayLoad>
<requestRows>****</requestRows>
<requestRowLength>1272</requestRowLength>
<exceptionTimestamp>2012070202281068-0700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionTimestamp>201$2070202281068-0700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionTimestamp>20120(702022810680700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionDetail>NO DATA AVAILABLE FOR TIME PERIOD SPECIFIED   =</exceptionDetail>
</PayLoad>
```

I have to find a entire tags that contain $,(,=,- characters. for this i have written below regular expression pattern 
`(<[\w\d]*>\w*(?<value>[^\w]+)\w*\d*</[\w\d]*>)`
and it returns following output(running in Expresso Tool)

```
<requestRows>****</requestRows>
<exceptionTimestamp>2012070202281068-0700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionTimestamp>20120(702022810680700</exceptionTimestamp>
```

but it should return below two enrty also.

```
<exceptionTimestamp>201$2070202281068-0700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionDetail>NO DATA AVAILABLE FOR TIME PERIOD SPECIFIED   =</exceptionDetail>
```

these entries omitted because it contains more than one special characters(including space). Can anyone please give me a correct regular expression for the above scenario.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you attempting simply to find if the row matches or are you actually attempting to discover the offending character with your backreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use lookaround for the mid part, so instead of

```
(<[\w\d]*>\w*(?<value>[^\w]+)\w*\d*</[\w\d]*>)
```

I would use

```
(<[\w\d]*>(?=[^<]*[^<\w])(?<value>.*)</[\w\d]*>)
```

Without the `?<value>` part that I don't really recognise the syntax of, this becomes

```
(<[\w\d]*>(?=[^<]*[^<\w]).*</[\w\d]*>)
```

Just add capturing groups where you like if you want to save anything in particular.

Comment: Thanks For the reply, I am getting error message like "To many )'s". I am using Expresso Tool.

Comment: I edited to add a `*` I had missed, but otherwise it seems to work , see [this link](http://rubular.com/r/qmNLqc34X4). I have omitted the named group here, since I don't know which flavour you are using, I just copied your syntax for that part.

Comment: Last one works fine , but it returns <requestRowLength>1272</requestRowLength> this tag also.I want tags entries that contain special characters. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, missed one thing. Easily fixed though, edited to add a `<` in the lookaround expression.